# The integral $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt[y]{y}} dy$ and the differential equation $y = \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^y$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I couldn't find a question about this integral, sorry if a similar question has been asked before.

For fun, I came up with the differential equation:

$$y = \frac{dy}{dx}^{{\frac{dy}{dx}}^{{\frac{dy}{dx}}^{.^{.^.}}}} = \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^y$$

Taking the $y$-th root on both sides leaves us with a separable differential equation:

$$\sqrt[y]{y} = \frac{dy}{dx}$$

And then solving it (using separation) leaves us with

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt[y]{y}} dy = x + C$$

This integral looks similar to integral in the famous [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream), but it's not quite it. Anyways, I'm unable to solve it, and since [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%201%2Fx%5E%281%2Fx%29) also is unable to do produce anything useful I'm asking here.

**Questions**

1. It seems that this integral doesn't have a known result, but is is anyone still able to find something useful about it? And in best case maybe solve the differential equation?
2. Can the differential equation be solved in some other way than separation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are expecting a closed form for the antiderivative, stop *dreaming* !

For a definite integral you could use
$$y^{-1/y}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{ \log ^n\left({y}\right)}{n!\,y^n}$$ Now
$$\int \log ^n\left({y}\right)\,{y^{-n}}\,dy=\int e^{-(n-1) t} t^n\,dt=-t^{n+1} E_{-n}((n-1) t)$$

Now, numerically
$$f(p)=\int_1^p y^{-1/y}\,dy$$ is a very smooth function which looks like
$$f(p) \sim a\, p^b \,\log^c(p)$$

A quick and dirty nonlinear regression (for $1 \leq p\leq 1000$) gives $(R^2 > 0.999999)$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence
   Interval} \\
 a & 0.44658 & 0.00038 & \{0.44583,0.44733\} \\
 b & 0.91265 & 0.00017 & \{0.91233,0.91298\} \\
 c & 0.71671 & 0.00103 & \{0.71468,0.71874\} \\
\end{array}$$